# Haskell - how can I convert string to integer and pass it to created structure?

Tags: haskell

I'm implementing [CIS 194](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html) course and found one task I can't solve.

I have a `LogMessage` data:

```
type TimeStamp = Int
data LogMessage = LogMessage MessageType TimeStamp String
                | Unknown String
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

And I want to create a `LogMessage` by sending array (like `["I", "215" "somesomesome"]`) to it:

```
createLogMessage :: [String] -> LogMessage
createLogMessage ("I":timestamp:message) = LogMessage Info timestamp message
```

The problem is that timestamp should be converted to integer. How can I convert timestamp to integer and pass it to create a `LogMessage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Read` class provides the function `read :: Read a => String -> a` for just this type of conversion. (Also, you need to unpack `message` from the list as well, so that `LogMessage` gets a `String`, not a `[String]`, as its third argument.)

```
createLogMessage :: [String] -> LogMessage
createLogMessage ("I":timestamp:message:[]) = LogMessage Info (read timestamp) message
```

or more simply

```
createLogMessage ["I", timestamp, message] = LogMessage Info (read timestamp) message
```

The `Int` class is an instance of `Read`, and Haskell can infer that `read` needs to return an `Int` here.

Note that if your `MessageType` is an instance of `Read`, you can simplify `createLogMessage`.

```
instance Read MessageType where
    read "I" = Info
    read "D" = Debug
    -- etc

createLogMessage :: [String] -> LogMessage
createLogMessage [msgType, timestamp, message] = LogMessage (read msgType) (read timestamp) message
```

Comment: LogAnalysis.hs:11:46:
    Couldn't match expected type `String -> LogMessage'
                with actual type `LogMessage'
    The function `LogMessage' is applied to four arguments,
    but its type `MessageType -> TimeStamp -> String -> LogMessage'
    has only three
    In the expression: LogMessage Info read (timestamp) message
    In an equation for `createLogMessage':
        createLogMessage ["I", timestamp, message]
          = LogMessage Info read (timestamp) message

Comment: LogAnalysis.hs:11:62:
    Couldn't match type `String -> a0' with `Int'
    Expected type: TimeStamp
      Actual type: String -> a0
    In the second argument of `LogMessage', namely `read'
    In the expression: LogMessage Info read (timestamp) message
    In an equation for `createLogMessage':
        createLogMessage ["I", timestamp, message]
          = LogMessage Info read (timestamp) message
Failed, modules loaded: Log.

Comment: You misplaced the parentheses; it's `(read timestamp)`, not `read (timestamp)`.